# IDA hex-rays decompiler not loaded

Tags: ida, decompiler

I have an executable that is  c++(x64)  compiled code upon which the decompiler is not loaded. In other files, it works fine. But they are mostly written in c. 
I am not sure if it is a limitation in version 6.8.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the decompiler is not loaded"?

Comment: I mean it is not shown in plugins menu/ not responding to F5. And a message about the loading of the plugin doesn't appear in IDA messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that I was trying to open a 32bit file in idaq64 and so the decompiler doesn't work.